# Get the first item of some group in a single SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I do something like this *every single day* - it would be one of my most common queries:

```sql
select * from 
   (select columns, rownumber() over (partition by something) as number from whatever) x
where x = 1
```

Which is horrible and seems like there's a lot of extra stuff that shouldn't be needed - a subselect, an alias for the sub select, another select statement - and at best you end up with an extra column in your output - at worst you have to re-list a bunch of columns.

Obviously, what *I want to do* is not valid SQL because of the order of operations:

```sql
select * from whatever where rownumber() over (partition by something) = 1
```

And while this *looks* like it could work, it actually gives a very wrong answer:

```sql
select * from whatever,
    lateral (select rownumber() over (partition by something) as number)
where number = 1
```

`first_value()` seems like it should get you there - but you still end up with lots of rows:

```sql
select first_value(key) over (partition by something), columns from whatever
```

But I keep thinking that there's a way of achieving it and wasting a lot of time trying.

So, the **question**, is it possible to achieve it ***without using a subselect?***

Essentially, I want only one of every item matching a single condition, eg., the first item of every order each month, the biggest item in each set, a single test example of each of these different cases etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A textbook example for `DISTINCT ON`!

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (something) columns FROM whatever;
```

Without `ORDER BY`, you get an arbitrary pick from each set with the same `something`. Add `ORDER BY something, something_else` to decide which row to pick.

See (with ample details):

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

[And it's faster, too.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715134/939860)

Comment: wow it worked - my life has been improved.

Comment: That's the stuff! :)